# Flag for off-topic software recommendation declined, discussion

Tags: discussion, off-topic, flagging

I flagged this post as off-topic as a request for software recommendations, but it was declined. In my opinion, the question is such that the only possible valid answers to it are tool recommendations. Plus, the question directly asks for a recommendation for a tool.

[How do I get a production website to load assets from local web server?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21765/how-do-i-get-a-production-website-to-load-assets-from-local-web-server)

I'd like to get a second opinion. Hopefully discussion of this post isn't considered too frivolous for meta. Thanks.

Comment: Not I either, I tend to accept flags as "helpful" if there's any validity to them so as not to discourage users from flagging in the future, which is an important part of community involvement. I agree with John here, I'd have probably just edited out that last line. If the primary focus of a question is for seeking recommendations, then it would be difficult to salvage and likely should be closed. As John also indicated, the consensus by the community to no longer accept questions for recommendations was made later down the road, so as we see older questions get responded to...

Comment: often due to spam or self-promotion, we either protect, lock, or close them depending on their content. Feel free to flag these as you see them too, and don't be reluctant to do so because of being declined, flags are always appreciated and keep us moderators on our toes and give us something to do :-)

Comment: You don't necessarily need to reference an external tool to answer that question - depending on the level of server access you have. _[I've added an answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/118813/1243)_

Comment: @MrWhite Awesome answer! My flag was predicated on the idea that an external tool was necessary, so I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't decline it but I probably would have declined the flag, too. The question is good with the possible exception of the last part where they essentially say recommending a tool for this be cool, too. I think editing that out would be sufficient to salvage the question.

If the question had been a blatant request for a tool, due to its age I would probably lock it instead. At the time requesting tools, etc, wasn't off topic as we were still refining how this site worked. I thinking locking it for historical reasons is more appropriate than closing it.

But that's just my take on it.

Comment: I declined the flag exactly for this reason.  An edit to remove the last few words would have been the appropriate action compared to flagging in this case.   Declined flags don't count against you in any way on this site.